# Expecting to get "non_field_errors: Unable to log in with provided credentials", but not getting it

Tags: django, axios

**Expectation**: when wrong login credentials are provided, "non_field_errors: Unable to log in with provided credentials" is returned, such as below (screenshot from a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u2RJXTtCn2Y&t=1316s) which I'm following verbatim)

[image]

**Reality**: instead I'm getting the error below.

[image]

This gets printed to the console:

> POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/token/login 400 (Bad Request)

Interestingly I get this same error when I try to create users with passwords that are too short. I'm not having any issues with axios or the server when I provide the right credentials for log in, or use passwords of sufficient length when creating new users. When trying to catch errors such as these that I'm failing to get the expected result.

My code for catching the error is the same as in the tutorial:

```
methods: {
    submitForm() {
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = ''
        localStorage.removeItem('token')

        const formData = {
            username: this.username,
            password: this.password
        }

        axios
            .post('/api/v1/token/login', formData)
            .then(response => {
                 const token = response.data.auth_token

                 this.$store.commit('setToken', token)

                 axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Token ' + token

                 localStorage.setItem('token', token)

                 this.$router.push('/dashboard/my-account')
             })
             .catch(error => {
                 if (error.response) {
                     for (const property in error.response) {
                     this.errors.push(`${property}: ${error.response.data[property]}`)
                     }
                 } else if (error.message) {
                     this.errors.push('Something went wrong. Please try again!')
                 }
            })
        
    }
}
```

Is there something in the server settings that I should change?
I'm using Django, rest framework, and djoser.

Comment: Have you also tried using postman to interact directly with the backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if you're using a custom exception handler in Django rest framework but it looks like the issue could be from the way you're handling the error in your frontend application.
You can handle the errors like this.

```
methods: {
    submitForm() {
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = ''
        localStorage.removeItem('token')

        const formData = {
            username: this.username,
            password: this.password
        }

        axios
            .post('/api/v1/token/login', formData)
            .then(response => {
                 const token = response.data.auth_token

                 this.$store.commit('setToken', token)

                 axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Token ' + token

                 localStorage.setItem('token', token)

                 this.$router.push('/dashboard/my-account')
             })
             .catch(error => {
                 if (error.response) {
                 // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
                 // that falls out of the range of 2xx
                   console.log(error.response.data);
                   console.log(error.response.status);
                   console.log(error.response.headers);
    } else if (error.request) {
      // The request was made but no response was received
      // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
      // http.ClientRequest in node.js
      console.log(error.request);
    } else {
      // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
      console.log('Error', error.message);
    }
    console.log(error.config);
  })
           
}
```

Can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57637381/how-to-display-error-messages-from-django-rest-framework-in-react)

Comment: Thanks, this does print to the console the "non_field_error". I'm not sure why I'm getting a different result to the tutorial when I have exactly the same code, but good to have this workaround.